# change width of array member when width is fixed with style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
JS/ANGULAR:
$scope.width = 10;
$scope.items = DATA taken from JSON about 2000 rows

CSS:
.theImage{width:100px}
.itemcontainer{width:100px}

<div class="container" id="container"> 
  <div class="itemcontainer" ng-repeat="item in items" style="{{width}}px">
     <div class="item">
       <img class="theImage" src="http://...." />
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what happens here is that the width of the item container is set with code to 10 pixels wide (it overrules the CSS). This can be changed to any width no wider as 100px. So it all becomes like a accordion. This all works find, what i want to do is that when i hover over an 'array-member' the 'itemContainer' that this one becomes 100px wide. i tried doing it with this but can't get it to function;

```
$('.itemcontainer').hover(function () {
     $(this).css("width", "100px");
     console.log("WORKS")
 });
```

I don't even get the 'works' in the console log, if i use a different element in my code it works fine. What would be a solution to make this one element change in size (AngularJS/Javascript/JQuery) ?

Comment: The code works fine for me. You can also do this with css only by the way. http://jsfiddle.net/ar5pL14z/2/

Comment: @Furkan; yes somehow it started to work here as well, don't know what went wrong. Thanks for you time Furkan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="container" id="container"> 
  <div class="itemcontainer" ng-repeat="item in items" style="width:10px">
     <div class="item">
       <img class="theImage" src="http://...." />
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.itemcontainer { background: orange; }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('.itemcontainer').hover(function () {
  $(this).css("width", "100px");
  console.log("WORKS")
});
```

Combined code of Furkan added as the answer

Answer (score 1):

add this CSS.

```
.itemcontainer:hover{
  width: 100px !important;
 }
```